# CLLocation returning negative speed

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, mapkit, core-location

I'm starting a new app which uses the coreLocation and the mapkit frameworks.

My problem is trying to get the current speed always returns me a negative value, i have take my iPhone with me to places with a good 3g signal and it doesn't matter, location.speed value is always -1.

here is the code which matters:

```
#define kRequiredAccuracy 1500.0 //meters
#define kMaxAge 60.0 //seconds
```

in the init method:

```
self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
```

then didUpdateToLocation:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSTimeInterval ageInSeconds = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);

    if( newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > kRequiredAccuracy || fabs(ageInSeconds) > kMaxAge )
    {
        NSLog(@"inacurate position");
        [self.delegate inacuratePosition];

    }
    else {

    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation andOldLocation:oldLocation];
    location=newLocation.coordinate;


    }


    if(tracking)
    {   
    [self updatePosition];
    }
    if(firstTime)
    {
        [self placeStartMark];
        firstTime=FALSE;
    }



}
```

and finally in the view controller in which I'm implementing the protocol:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)newLocation andOldLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation{

    double speed = [newLocation speed] *3.6;



    double altitude= [newLocation altitude];
    [self checkMaxSpeedAndAltitude:speed :altitude];
    if(speed< 0)
        speed=0;



    locationLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"speed: %f km/h   altitude: %f m", speed,altitude];
}
```

Im getting crazy so if anyone knows any solution it will be helpful for sure.
Thanks

Comment: You mention a good 3G signal when this is nearly irrelevant to 'good' location based applications.  If you don't have a view of satellites, you won't get good information.  Check that your horizontal accuracy is small (less than 200 meters), it's a good cheat to see that you have satellites and not just cell tower triangulation)

Comment: I have checked an even having a 65m horizontal accuracy, i receive a negative speed an altitude.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually, you get negative altitude and speed if the used location detection mechanism doesn't support it. For instance, when Wi-Fi or cell triangulation is used. Are you sure, you're getting GPS updates, so are you testing under the free sky? Even then, you'll still receive WiFi and cell tower location updates so you've to filter them out.

65 m horizontal accuracy is typical for Wi-Fi location updates.

Comment: Finally I get it working more less. Anyway thanks for the info, I didn't know that you couldn't get speed via wifi or cell location.

Comment: I am always getting negative speed. It doesn't matter whether i am using WiFi or cell tower or out in open sky. All other location parameters are correct.

Comment: You get negative speed when you don't have GPS.