# CLLocation not giving actual speed

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

Here is my location manager delegate code.

It is not giving speed when we move using car so at least speed value should change.

It always gives constant value -1.00.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    self.speedometerCurrentValue=crnLoc.speed;
    self.lblSpeed.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",crnLoc.speed];
}
```

Comment: CLLocation will give you the speed in metres per second, if it's getting an accurate enough location (i.e. it's getting it's location from the GPS chip). What are you expecting it to give you?

Comment: Hi james Snook .i am getting speed -1.0 every time. every time getting negative speed.

Comment: What accuracy are you asking for, and how are you testing? Also what accuracy are you actually getting?

Comment: actually when moving using car its not giving speed.always giving negative speed.

Comment: i am asking for not gives speed when we move using car also.so at least speed value should change.its always gives constant value -1.00.

Comment: Hi james Snook rply .

Comment: You don't get speed values unless the location your getting has sufficient accuracy, so it'd be good to know the what `crnLoc.horizontalAccuracy` is? Also have you checked the timestamp on the location, i.e. that it is a new location?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368684/cllocation-returning-negative-speed

Comment: Hey Anna i am using ios7 and ios8 update location method.-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{}but not getting speed.getting speed in negative.stack overflow previous question not helping me.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The linked question is still valid.

Comment: I suffer the same problem. Have you found a solution? @AlokKumar

Answer (score -1):

Please check this screenshot from apple explanations. Your speed is invalid.

[image]

Comment: The speed always return -1.0 sometimes