# iOS: CoreLocation Speed and Heading not working on physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some code that works 100% fine in the simulator. It shows heading and speed 100% correct; however; the second I run it on a proper device the speed and heading results are -1.

Anybody any ideas as to why? Or how to try and troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I guess this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368684/cllocation-returning-negative-speed will be useful for you.

Comment: How are you testing speed and heading on the simulator?

Comment: The simulated car journey / bike ride to get the speed and heading in the simulator. So basically does my app not have access to the GPS location then, just the significant changes one or something?

Comment: WOW - Turning off WiFi has solved the problem and given me a <30 horizontal accuracy figure. This never happened with the iPhone 5 and/or iOS7 - Is this a new thing?